# non-alphanumeric operator name leads to compile errors

Tags: scala

as long as alphanumeric named operators `piper` and `tapper` are used, things are fine.
(side note: copied from pipe and tap from Scala 2.13)

```
package playground

object NonAlphaOperatorName {

  implicit final class MyChainingOps[A](private val me: A) extends AnyVal {
    def piper[B](f: A => B): B = f(me)
    def tapper[B](f: A => B): A = {
      f(me)
      me
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    100 piper
      (r => r + 1) piper
      (r => r + 5) tapper
      (r => println(s"...$r...")) piper
      println
  }
}
```

Problem: when I **rename** `piper` to `|>` I get an compiler error "missing parameter type".

(Side note: renaming `piper` to `__` (double underscore) would be fine on the other hand)

```
package playground

object NonAlphaOperatorName {

  implicit final class MyChainingOps[A](private val me: A) extends AnyVal {
    def |>[B](f: A => B): B = f(me)
    def tapper[B](f: A => B): A = {
      f(me)
      me
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    100 |>
      (r => r + 1) |>
      (r => r + 5) tapper
      (r => println(s"...$r...")) |>    //error: missing parameter type [17:8]
      println
  }
}
```

Can you help me explain that problem and is there a solution for this problem in Scala 2.13?

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#infix-operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [different operator precedence](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#infix-operations) in your two examples.

In the first example, both `piper` and `tapper` have the same precedence, therefore the code is equivalent to the following fully parenthesized and "dotted" version:

```scala
100.piper(r => r + 1).piper(r => r + 5).tapper(r => println(s"...$r...")).piper(println)
```

In the second example, `|>` has higher precedence than `tapper`, therefore the code is equivalent to the following fully parenthesized and "dotted" version:

```scala
 100.|>(r => r + 1).|>(r => r + 5).tapper((r => println(s"...$r...")).|>(println))
```